# REACT: How to build object field selector hook similar to redux useSelector

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, mobx

I'm trying to build a hook which would return a selected subset of key-value pairs from an object. Assuming that the hook has access to an object which looks like this:

```
const stores = { someStore: { someField: 'fieldValue' } }
```

how can we pass a callback to a hook to select fields from the `stores` object?
The ideal scenario would be to have the hook work like this:

```
const {selectedField} = useStores(stores => ({ selectedField: stores.someStore.someField }))
```

The goal of this hook would be to replace MobX `@inject(stores => ({...}))` in my codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the selector against the `stores`

```js
function useStores(selector) {
  const stores = { someStore: { someField: 'fieldValue' } };
  
  return selector(stores); 
}

const { selectedField } = useStores(stores => ({ selectedField: stores.someStore.someField }));

console.log(selectedField);
```